# Looking to send data from our team site to our public site Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, synchronisation

So we have a teamsite, and a public site. I want an option in our teamsites document library to be able to send that document to the public site's document library in a specific folder. Like, if I clicked on test.doc I could choose send to Public Site Folder 1/Send to public Site folder 2/send to public site folder 3.

Here is the kicker though, I can't do anything via c#. I'm limited in a lot of what I can do. I can only add apps to the team site, and I tried using the sent to custom command, but it only lets me add one destination, not the 5 I need.
Any way to go about this?
Tried using workflows, the copy document command only lets me copy it in the same site.
Tried using content organizer, couldn't enable it on either site (locked down)
Looked into JS, not a strong JS programmer and the only stuff I found was for SharePoint 2007.

Any way to do this?

I have near full access on the team site, and I have access and I am able to use sharepoint designer for both sites. I cannot add apps on the public site.

Comment: If this is a requirement, can you not request and get the access you need? This seems a little unreasonable on the part of the admins.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't contribute to the public site, then there's no chance your JS method would work because you can't elevate privileges with JS, so it sounds to me you're locked out of pretty much every conceivable way you might make this happen.  You need to get access to add content organizer or content deployment or something.

*** EDIT ***

If you can contribute to both sites or at least view the team site you can use the Explorer view of the libraries and drag and drop content from one to the other. You have to use Internet Explorer (32-bit) to do that, however.

Comment: I have "Full control" on the public site, however. We are locked down where the .aspx control for adding apps has been removed. I also am unable to enable a lot of "site features" because they have been either locked down or removed by central adminstration. I cannot even add a document library or any of the default sharepoint "apps"  without going thru share point designer.

No chance of me getting more access. Might just have to stick with the sent to and not have it sorted.

On the team site I can do whatever I want, san add a content organizer. Which is also locked down.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I wish to be able to set up an option that a user would somehow click in order to move the files. Is there a way I could go about that? I know there are custom actions ,but those don't seem to work when trying to move between multiple SharePoint sites.

Comment: http://www.sharepointproducts.com/Pages/CopyMove2013-Overview.aspx here's a custom solution that claims to be able to allow people to copy/move files all over a farm.  OOB without doing any custom code I don't think it's possible.  I might be wrong, but I haven't dug up anything that didn't show a wsp solution or some other custom code that's not an option for you.  The explorer mode method is at least "doable" even if it's not a one-click answer.  I'll look around a little more, though.

Comment: Another option is: if you can have the team site extended to a public domain and share the files you want to with anonymous users, while leaving the rest of the site for authenticated users, there used to be a way to add documents to a library that was sort of like a logical link.  Basically the file still lives where it is but you have a link to it in your library with metadata, etc.  I might be idealizing that idea a little since I've never really used it.